# Аналог Spring @Controller в Java Servlet

Tags: java, spring, servlet, controller

Спринговые контроллеры (`@Controller`) позволяют обрабатывать множество URL - паттернов. А как быть с сервлетами, один сервлет на один `url`?
Спасибо.

Comment: Spring @Controller это надстройка над Servlet-ами. Spring устанавливает свой Servlet, который работает для всех url и перенаправляет запрос к конкретному контролёру. Учите мат.часть, вроде никто этого в секрете не держит и всё можно найти в той же документации по Spring-у. А уж по servlet-ам даже на русском материалов до... много короче ещё со времён первого появления этой технологии.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, сервлет - это приложение, которое ловит все внутри выделенного ему context path. Вам нужно сделать роутер, который будет разбирать url и вызывать соответствующий код (контроллер). Собственно, этим и занимается спринг, вы можете без труда повторить его основу, создав аналогичную аннотацию, сканируя в рантайме пакет с вашим приложением и находя соответствие текущего URL заданному в аннотации.

Comment: Собственно context вместе с contex path-ем выделяется действительно приложению. Но servlet != приложение. Это его составная часть. Их может быть много, может быть один.